# JavaScript event handling

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want the program to handle `keydown` messages after the table is printed (after clicking the button). Before the button is clicked, the program handles `keydown` message, but after I click the button it doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var matrix,xbody,ybody,dir,key;
function draw()
{
    for(var i=0;i<xbody.length;i++)
    {
        matrix[xbody[i]*50+ybody[i]].bgColor="black";
    }
alert("draw");
}
function init()
{
document.write("<table id='mine' align='center' height='500px' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='500px' border='4' >");
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for( var j=0;j<50;j++)
    document.write("<td></td>");        
    document.write("</tr>");
    }
document.write("</table></div>");
matrix=mine.getElementsByTagName("td");
xbody=new Array();
ybody=new Array();
xbody[0]=ybody[0]=0;
draw();
alert("pop");
}

function keypress(e)
{
alert("aiyoooo");
if((e.keyCode==38)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==38)))
key=0;
else if((e.keyCode==40)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==40)))
key=1;
else if((e.keyCode==37)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==37)))
key=2;
else if((e.keyCode==39)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==39)))
key=3;
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown=keypress(event)>
<br/>
<input type="button" onClick="init()" value="play">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to re-copy the HTML you pasted, then select it and click the Code button. Now much of your HTML has been filtered out by the StackOverflow software.

Comment: @Nick Craver: are you sure this is all there was?

Comment: @MvanGeest - Yup, it's pretty clear to see when you edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Chrome ... instead of defining the on keydown as an attribute of the body tag, just do this in your script tag.

```
document.onkeydown = function ()
{
    var e = event;
    alert( "keycode:" + e.keyCode );
    if((e.keyCode==38)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==38)))
        key=0;
   // continued ...
```

Comment: thanks man, it is working beautifully.

in my lab they don't have chrome and i am not supposed to install it... any idea how to make it work for IE or firefox?